# Laravel Excel import CSV load data

Tags: php, excel, laravel, csv, import

i have this CSV(without row headers)

```
001001,BENITEZ LI,2052,2059,2016-04-27 09:07:20
001002,CASA PARRO,13937,13945,2016-04-21 09:07:20
001004,NUEVO BANC,701,709,2016-04-23 22:07:20
```

Using this script:

```
Excel::filter('chunk')->load(public_path().'/uploads/'.$filename)->chunk(250, function($results) {
                    foreach ($results as $row) {
                        $user = Lectura::create([
                            'partida' => $row->partida,
                            'nombre' => $row->nombre,
                            'lectura_ant' => $row->lectura_ant,
                            'lectura_act' => $row->lectura_act,
                            'fecha' => $row->fecha,                                       
                        ]);
                    }
                });
```

I want import to my DB using this code, i can get correctly each line. But added null values. Dumping variable:

```
CellCollection {#734 ▼
  #title: null
  #items: array:5 [▼
    "001001" => "001002"
    "benitez_li" => "CASA PARRO"
    2052 => 13937.0
    2059 => 13945.0
    "2016_04_27_090720" => "2016-04-21 09:07:20"
  ]
}
```

Perhaps should be (how can define column names?):

```
CellCollection {#734 ▼
  #title: null
  #items: array:5 [▼
    "partida" => "001002"
    "nombre" => "CASA PARRO"
    "lectura_ant"=> 13937.0
    "lectura_act"=> 13945.0
    "fecha" => "2016-04-21 09:07:20"
  ]
}
```

or better (convert to array). How can get values? $row[1], $row[2]....

```
CellCollection {#734 ▼
  #title: null
  #items: array:5 [▼
    "0" => "001002"
    "1" => "CASA PARRO"
    "2"=> 13937.0
    "3"=> 13945.0
    "4" => "2016-04-21 09:07:20"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you set the $fillable variable in your Model? For Mass assignment you have to set it.
`protected $fillable = [
        'partida', 'nombre', 'lectura_ant', 'lectura_act', 'fecha'
    ];`

Comment: Thanks Andy. Yes, all filliable. I solved adding two lines                     $reader->toArray();
$reader->noHeading();

Answer (score 1):

Solved !! Adding two lines:

```
        $rows = Excel::load(public_path().'/uploads/'.$filename, function($reader) {
            $reader->toArray();
            $reader->noHeading();
        })->get();

       foreach ($rows as $row) {
           $item = array([
                'partida' => $row[0],
                'nombre' => $row[1],
                'lectura_ant' => $row[2],
                'lectura_act' => $row[3],
                'fecha' => $row[4], 
            ]);
            DB::table('lecturas_temp')->insert($item );
        }
```

Comment: Your are great! @Alejandro